# using layout(toggleButton) inside alert dialog, always returns nullPointerExpection

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog, togglebutton

in my `MainActivity` i have a method `showPopUp` that is called by a button's listener. So `MainActivity's` layout only contain a button.

`ShowPopUp` method reads button states and returns `null pointer expception`.
`activity_toggle` is my layout that contains `toggleButton`.
following is my mainactivity code snippet.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  ToggleButton toggleButton;
  String i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this);
}

public void showAlertDialog(final Context context){
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_toggle,null);
ab.setView(v);
ab.setTitle("toggle mera dil toggle meri jaan");
   toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);


toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(toggleButton.isChecked()){
                i+=i;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button is on "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button is off  mode",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
});
ab.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ok button pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    boolean tButton = toggleButton.isChecked();
    if(tButton){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button is off on a ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
}
});
ab.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
ab.create().show();
}
}
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.alienslab.alarmclock, PID: 19176
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.alienslab.alarmclock.AddAlarmActivity$1.onClick(AddAlarmActivity.java:111)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. You have to give reference of View when you find view from inflater view.

**toggleButton = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);**

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_toggle,null);
ab.setView(v);
ab.setTitle("toggle mera dil toggle meri jaan");
toggleButton = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `v` View object which passing in `setView` method of `AlertDialog`  for accessing `ToggleButton` from Dialog layout:

```
 toggleButton = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
```

This line find view in your activity but this `R.id.toggleButton1` control is defined in `activity_toggle.xml` layout which is used in dialog.
Try the

```
toggleButton = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
```